Can I read other users files in Linux filesystem if I have their username and password without switching or logging into that user?
I know this is possible by switching to root or using 'sudo' but I just want to know if there is any other way. Assume the user doesn't have root privileges.
Scenario:
While playing a CTF challenge, I gained reverse shell access to the www-data user using Netcat. I also have the credentials for another user, but when I tried to switch to that user , I was not allowed to do so. Additionally, the current user does not have root privileges, so I have this doubt
as user68186 suggested this answer Share a Folder between two Local Users but it didn't resolve my issue. The suggested answers involve changing the group name or using sudo, but I don't have the necessary permissions for those actions.

This question is similar to: Share a Folder between two Local Users. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for suggesting answer but it didn't resolve my issue also I have added a scenario to make my question clear.

Yes, as long as those files have default settings (you can see files /home/$USER/ but not access most of the hidden directories (if not all)). A normal user and the admin can remove permissions for other users if they like and then viewing is not possible.
You can not delete, or edit files unless those permissions have been added (by that user or the admin).

I was able to see the other user's files and their permissions. The current user doesn't have read or write permissions. So, according to your answer, in this case, the current user can't read the other user's files despite having credentials.

Could you please confirm this?

please read up on permissions. files and dirs are created with defaults (755 and 644) If you set a file to 600 ONLY the user self (and anyone being able to invoke sudo or a root prompt) can view a file.
